# Xamarin iOS: Do all images need to be in the Asset Catalogue?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Visual Studio 2019 (Windows)
Xamarin 4.6.0.847

I will start with the actual question  (there is a second, related question at the end):

Do I have to include all images inside the asset catalogue when publishing an iOS App to the Apple store / TestFlight etc?

I noticed, that although the images show up when I run the App on an iPhone connected to my MAC, they are nowhere to be found in the XCode project.  Therefore I am concerned they are not being uploaded to Apple as part of my latest build.  All of my images are PNG and within the Resources folder.

It's the first build I have uploaded, so I guess I'll just have to wait and see (approx a weeks time apparently).

I also noticed the launchscreen.storyboard on my PC is not the same as the one in the XCode project.  Why is it not being copied across?

But in the meantime, I could upload another build if the images DO need to be in the Asset catalogue.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have images outside the asset catalog? How are you providing the correct image per screen resolution if you don't use the asset catalog?

Comment: Because the specific images look OK on all of the emulators and the iPhone I have.  There are about 60 images in the App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it is preferable to use `Asset Catalogue`, you can safely go with putting all your images in the `Resources` folder as well. I would strongly advise you not to go with the `Resources` approach due to a couple of reasons:

1. The management for images is a lot easier with `Asset Catalogue`
2. You can also easily put `*.pdf` files and reference them across multiple platforms & resolutions inside the `Contents.json` file.
3. You cannot theme your app (have both light & dark theme) with `Resources` folder approach.

If you don't plan any of that, or don't want to take the time to move everything into the `Asset Catalogue`, you can safely stat with the `Resources` approach, at least for now. I haven't seen any plans from Apple to remove this functionality.

About the `launchscreen.storyboard` - this is a known issue with iOS and Xamarin. Occasionally, the build process doesn't think that the storyboard file has been updated and simply ignores it during the build. What you can do is:

1. Delete `bin` & `obj` folders for the iOS project on your Windows machine;
2. Delete the build files on your Mac machine. They are located in `/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/`. You can delete only your current project's build folder - you don't need to delete all of the other projects' builds.
3. Rebuild & deploy your project and everything should be fine.

P.S. Keep in mind that sometimes the iOS device can also cache the file, so an uninstall and reboot of the device may be required.

Comment: Mihail - Thank you.  I will action this today and upload another build.  I may even go the Asset Catalogue way for all of my images.  At least the 1x version of them.

Comment: All my images are now in the Asset Catalogue.  I had a few issue's with file not found and removed the references from the Project file.  However, I am now being told this file is missing, but I cannot find a reference to is anywhere.    Could not find file "/Users/MyUser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.Mobile.iOS/b97b05343d52097d681db173220d856c/obj/iPhone/Debug/actool/bundle/AppIcon60x60@2x.png"  I've deleted the cache/MyApp from the MAC, the bin/obj on PC, removed the App from the iPhone, rebooted the iphone, but still get this error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it is still being referenced somewhere in your csproj file. Open for editing your iOS.csproj file and look for it. If it is not there, then you must add its reference, since someone is looking for this file. Either reference it, or remove the link from where it is being referenced (most likely some Icon catalog).

Comment: Where in the Asset Catalogue should I add that?  In another AppIcon set?

Comment: Yes, your application's icon should be an `AppIcon` set. There, you will also have the options to add *Spotlight*, *Settings* and a lot of other icons for your app. You can see the necessary dimensions and steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=macos#managing-icons-with-asset-catalogs

Comment: I already have that full of Icons of the correct size.  And they show up on the Project on the MAC too.

Comment: Like I said, check your references in either your iOS.csproj file or your Content.json file. One of them should have an incorrect reference to this image (or missing one). Search for `AppIcon60x60@2x`

Comment: It's working on the emulators on the PC. but still the error is there when i try to compile/run on the iPhone connected to the MAC.  Rebooted iPhone, problem still exists only when i choose to deploy to the iPhone  is on version 12.4 (which is my build level). Emulators are on 13. Just updating it to 12.4.7 (don't think it will take 13).  Then I will try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216411/discussion-between-mihail-duchev-and-rob-l).